# AttributeError: 'Projection' object has no attribute 'u' gensim python lsi

Tags: python-2.7, tf-idf, gensim

when I try and load the model and do anything with it I always get : "`AttributeError: 'Projection' object has no attribute 'u'`"

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Not sure if I am saving the model incorrectly or loading it incorrectly.

```
index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsiModel[tfIdfModel[myCorpus]])
File "/home/analytics/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models /lsimodel.py", line 405, 
in __getitem__ 
assert self.projection.u is not None, "decomposition not initialized yet"   
AttributeError: 'Projection' object has no attribute 'u'
```

Comment: Hi! Actually the community needs some more information to be able to help. Please read what is meant by a [MCVE]. Thank you!